# Firebase Document Write Limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redis, nosql, google-cloud-functions

Hey so with my current feed database design, I am using Redis for the cache for super-fast reads, which are routed through my Google Cloud Functions. The Redis database handles all post data and timeline updates, which is great and all, but I forgot one of the most considerable caveats to this. Firebase Firestore only permits [one document write per second](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions), meaning that if I have a document that stores the post data (post_id, user_id, content, like_count), the like_count would be impossible to track with the possibility for many likes per second. Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [shard your counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) among multiple documents and query them in aggregate as needed.

You can also try [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) queue to smooth out the write frequency.  It will add considerable complexity to the system, but is really the only genericized way in GCP to manage the rate of some work.  This might not work out the way you need, however.

If you use Cloud Tasks, your task will need to be [configured](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues) with a rate limit, and it will have to deliver the document data to write to yet another function or other HTTP endpoint that will perform the write.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems like there should be a better way of handling this. I'm going to wait for any other responses before I make a final decision.

Comment: The fact that there is a whole page of documentation (and also an official [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-counter)) to deal with sharded counters kind of suggests that this is really the way to go, without adding more complexity.

Comment: Ended up going with the sharded counter